# Android: how to unit test the joystick API?

Tags: android, unit-testing

Is it possible to unit test the **Android joystick API**?  For example, the Android legacy sample **ApiDemos** has an activity called **GameControllerInput**.  It looks as if the activity handles incoming `MotionEvents` in the `dispatchGenericMotionEvent` method:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Check that the event came from a joystick since a generic motion event
    // could be almost anything.
    if (isJoystick(event.getSource())
            && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // Update device state for visualization and logging.
        InputDeviceState state = getInputDeviceState(event.getDeviceId());
        if (state != null && state.onJoystickMotion(event)) {
            mSummaryAdapter.show(state);
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(event);
}
```

How can I send `MotionEvents` from a unit test application (executing in a test thread) that are then received by the **GameControllerInput** activity?